# SImilar command in R for Python pandas.Series.replace

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I don't use R usually so I don't know the best way in this language to achieve my goal.
I need to replace some values in a dataframe df with other values contained in a csv file. My initial thought was something like

- Create a dictionary-like structure (like in python) from the replacement csv file
- Find a function that replace values based on another object
  I have no idea how to do that in R, do you have any idea?

  Example

  ```
    a <- c('a','b','c')
    key <- data.frame(a)

    b <- c('d','e','f')
    values <- data.frame(b)

    col1 <- c('a','c','b')
    col2 <- c(4,5,6)
    df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
    ...

    ncol1 <- c('d','f','e')
    expected_df <- data.frame(ncol1,col2)
  ```

Comment: Check out the [replace](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/replace) function. If you provide a reproducible example we may be able to provide more concrete help.

Comment: I would like something as replace(df, key, values) to do what I have in mind. I know that's not how replace work but I'm looking for a different function.